# readlines function with input returning zero

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to read a long txt file in python and break it up in parts. I read that readlines would solve this problem.

```
f=open('longtext.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines(size_of_longtext/number_of_parts)
```

However, when I do this, lines just become an empty array. After this when I type

```
lines=f.readlines()
```

lines is still []. Can anyone explain what's causing this?

Comment: what is the value of `size_of_longtext/number_of_parts`

Comment: The file itself is around 150000 bytes, so size_of_longtext/number_of_parts somewhere is between 10000 to 75000 depending on the desired parts

Comment: I am using Python 3

Answer (score 1):

Remember to do a:

```
f.seek(0)
```

if you want to re-read the file before your

```
lines=f.readlines()
```

If you've already read the file to the end, then the file pointer is at the EOF. Also make sure you are in the correct directory for the file to be read and you're not reading an empty file in another directory.

```
print (os.getcwd())
```

will tell you what directory your script is reading the file from.